# Unable to install 'node-red-contrib-tf-model' using NPM on windows10x64

Tags: npm, npm-install, node-red, tensorflow.js, tfjs-node

I followed the tutorials below for the installation of the tensorflow model:

- https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-contrib-tf-model
- https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/blob/master/tfjs-node/WINDOWS_TROUBLESHOOTING.md

**Steps taken:**

1. I first installed the `@tensorflow/tfjs-node` inside Node-RED directly by running the following code:

   ```
   C:\Users\username\.node-red\node_modules> npm install @tensorflow/tfjs-node@1.4.0
   ```
2. Ran `npm install` under `C:\Users\username\.node-red\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node`:

   ```
   C:\Users\username\.node-red\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node> npm install
   ```
3. Finally ran `npm install node-red-contrib-tf-model` in the same directory:

   ```
   C:\Users\username\.node-red\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node> npm install node-red-contrib-tf-model
   ```

**Error that occured:**

> ```
> npm WARN node-red-contrib-tf-model@0.1.11 requires a peer of @tensorflow/tfjs-node@^1.4.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
> npm WARN @tensorflow/tfjs-node@1.4.0 No license field.
> ```

I have installed the correct tfjs-node version, and so why does this error occur?

Edit: Tried installing the module straight from Node-RED itself and got the following

```
ERROR:The specified module could not be found.
C:\Users\username\.node-red\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node\lib\napi-v6\tfjs_binding.node
```

When I checked the above directory it turns out that I do have the 'tfjs_binding.node'.

What am I doing wrong here? Can someone please help me out.

Comment: you appear to be a directory too deep when running `npm` you should normally be running it in `C:\Users\username\.node-red\` (note the `\` between `username` and `.node-red`) not in the `node_modules` directory

Comment: @hardillbTried the above and still got the same error.